# How can I use the scope model to have my inherited widgets all persistent during bottom navigation bar using flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-plugin, flutter-navigation, flutter-packages

I am learning new features about the flutter framework but what I am interested in right now is to know how I can keep my inherited widgets using the scope model to keep all my pages persistent during bottom navigation bar page navigation?

Comment: so you are using `InheritedWidget`s or `ScopeModel`s?

Comment: I am using scope model

Comment: can you please be a bit more specific about what you are trying to achieve, what you have already tried and what did not work. In the best case provide a short code sample which reproduces your problem.

Comment: I just want to know how I can use the scope model to have all my pages persistent it's something I don't know how to do

Comment: post your current code then

Comment: I don't have a code problem it's just something I don't know how to do... I was wondering if I can get some basic instructions on how to accomplish this